# Spark and JDBC: Iterating through large table and writing to hdfs

Tags: apache-spark, hive, hdfs, apache-spark-sql

What would be the most memory efficient way to copy the contents of a large relational table using spark and then write to a partitioned Hive table in parquet format (without sqoop). I have a basic spark app and i have done some other tuning with spark's jdbc but data in relational table is still 0.5 TB and 2 Billion records so I although I can lazy load the full table, I'm trying to figure out how to efficiently partition by date and save to hdfs without running into memory issues. since the jdbc `load()` from spark will load everything into memory I was thinking of looping through the dates in the database query but still not sure how to make sure I don't run out of memory.

Comment: Did you get an answer to this question?

Answer (score 0):

If you need to use Spark you can add to your application `date` parameter for filtering table by date and run your Spark application in loop for each date. You can use bash or other scripting language for this loop.

This can look like:

- foreach date in dates

  - `spark-submit` your application with `date` parameter
  - read DB table with `spark.read.jdbc`
  - filter by `date` using `filter` method
  - write result to HDFS with `df.write.parquet("hdfs://path")`

Another option is to use different technology for example implement Scala application using JDBC and DB cursor to iterate through rows and save result to HDFS. This is more complex, because you need to solve problems related to writing to Parquet format and saving to HDFS using Scala. If you want I can provide Scala code responsible for writing to Parquet format.

Comment: but if I loop through an array of dates for example and looping the `jdbc.read` through those dates, won't I still continue to fill up memory continually with each consecutive `load()` statement or did you mean something else?

Comment: I mean running this loop in some script language e.g bash and sumbitting your Spark application, so I don't mean implementing this loop in Scala, because indeed you would still have problem with memory.